# Check if Form is closing

Tags: c#

I have a method that fires on a "Leave" event:

```
private void cmbBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool error = true;

    if (something == true)
    { 
        //do stuff...
        error = false;
    } 

    if (error == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!")
    }
}
```

Problem is, that closing the form counts as "leaving focus" from the control, so when I close the form, the message box pops up. Is there a way I can catch the Form closing as an invalid parameter? I.e.

```
if (error == true && this.FormClosing == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!")
}
```

Comment: subscribe for `FormClosing` event which triggers before the form is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event instead of `Leave`.

Then in `FormClosing`, you can set `this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;` and your validation won't be fired any more.

If you close the form via an OK or Cancel button, you may need to set `CausesValidation = false` on those buttons as well (maybe you want validation on OK, though).